# How can I binding a event with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

This is a input label,

```
<input type="text" (blur) = "obj.action"/>
```

the obj is a object from corresponding component, `obj.action = preCheck($event)`, `preCheck(input: any) { code ....}` is a function in the same component, could it works if i code like this?

My purpose is to distinguish which input need this event, because there are few input use the same template, i want to use attr action to ensure which one need this event.

Comment: Could you please be more precise? What is your goal? Do you want to update an input element if obj.action is fired? Or do you want obj.action to be updated if (blur) is fired?

Comment: @DiabolicWords there are more than one text box use this input label, only one text box has blur event, so I don't want to add event to all the input label, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There is just one small mistake in this code, you didn't add the parentheses "()" when adding "obj.action" as the blur event handler. So the corrected code is :-

```
<input type="text" (blur) = "obj.action()"/>
```

Comment: obj is a object from corresponding component and `obj.action = "preCheck($event)" `,  i want to add a event here and the function is preCheck($event), while it not works, maybe it doesn't allow.